# Error al crear archivo "Cannot create a file when that file already exist "

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, directorioactivo

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo a partir de un llamado de un servicio web.

Cuando lo ejecuto me aparece el error `Cannot create a file when that file already exist`

Segun el debug, el código se cae en la linea `File.Move(originalFileName, newFileName);`
Aquí esta mi código, podrian decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

```
string testExport = proj.ProjectTitle; ;
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"D:\\testExport\\{0}_.zip", testExport); 
byte[] MyBinFiles = db.GetResponse(AllProjectIds);

DirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile);

String finalPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile),
               Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outCsvFile)
              + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms")
              + Path.GetExtension(outCsvFile));


Console.WriteLine("Create ZIP: " + finalPath);

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, MyBinFiles);

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("WriteAllBytes :  " + finalPath);


string zipFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outCsvFile)
              + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms");


while (!FileExtract(finalPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile)))
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

while (!FileDelete(finalPath))
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

//Thread.Sleep(1000);

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile));


foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles("*.csv"))
{
    if (!(file.Name.IndexOf("__") >= 0))
    {
        string originalFileName = file.FullName;
        int y = file.Name.IndexOf("_");
        string newFileName = zipFileName + file.Name.Substring(y);
        newFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile) + @"\" + newFileName;
        File.Move(originalFileName, newFileName);

        files.Add(newFileName);
    }

}
string zipFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ZipFolder"].ToString();

//ZipAllFiles
while (!ZipAllFiles(DirectoryName, zipFolder))
{
  hread.Sleep(1000);
}

onsole.WriteLine("Deleting All Csv file");
```

Comment: Hay ya un archivo con la misma nombre alli?

Comment: segun lo que veo cuando debuggin no hay nigun archivo con el mismo nombre, cuando pasa por el forach el nombre cambia

Answer (score 1):

Si suponemos que "en verdad no existe un archivo con el mismo nombre", en tu caso me parece que al realizar el `Substring()` en esta línea:

```
string newFileName = zipFileName + file.Name.Substring(y);
```

estas obteniendo no una ruta de archivo, tal vez algo que parece un directorio:

```
"c:\datos\mi_archivo_nuevo"
```

asegurate que se obtenga la ruta del archivo para la variable `newFileName`

```
"c:\datos\mi_archivo_nuevo.csv"
```

esto, para que puedas realizar :

```
  File.Move(@"c:\datos\mi_archivo_original.csv", @"c:\datos\mi_archivo_nuevo.csv");
```

- Otra cosa que puede estar sucediendo es que el folder donde deseas mover el archivo no existe!.

Comment: Hola tienes toda la razon, segun el break point que realize estoy obteniendo un nombre no la ruta del archivo. El folder donde estoy moviendo el archivo si existe. De que forma me puedo asegurar que paso la ruta del archivo?

Comment: Hola, verificando mejor veo que obtengo bien la ruta del archivo en la variable newFileName. Llendo mas abajo veo que se cae en la linea  string zipFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ZipFolder"].ToString(); me dice que Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: no necesitas usar toString(); ,únicamente: string zipFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ZipFolder"]; y asegura este definida en el config!

Comment: Si me funciona quitando el toString() el unico problema esque me repite el mismo nombre del archivo en la variable string testExport = proj.ProjectTitle;  y no cambia los nombres segun el foreach que deberia tener todos los ProjectTitle

Answer (score 0):

Si ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre, o borras antes el archivo y luego lo mueves o lo reemplazas ( generando una copia de seguridad del viejo archivo ).

Para eliminarlo antes de mover :

```
using System.IO;

...
...

if (File.Exists (archivoDestino_Path))  
   File.Delete (archivoDestino_Path);

File.Move (archivoFuente_Path, archivoDestino_Path);

...
```

---

Pero por lo que comentas, ya se generó el archivo anteriormente. Entonces, si lo que queremos es reemplazar *archivoDestino_Path* , y guardar una copia de respaldo del viejo *archivoDestino_Path* :

```
 Using System.IO;

 ...
 ...

 File.Replace (archivoFuente_Path, archivoDestino_Path, archivoBackUp_Path);

 ...
```